# Not receiving GPS location in emulator in Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, gps, emulation

I am not able to receive GPS locations in my app running in the emulator. I setup a a location listener as follows:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, interval, 0, locationListener);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, interval, 0, locationListener);
```

This works fine on a real device and in the emulator it doesn't generate an exception when this code gets executed. But the actual listener never gets called, whether I send the GPS location via DDMS or telnet. On a real device, the listener does work.

I do notice on Android's statusbar that the GPS icon is visible and it indicates that location is set by GPS, so everything seems to be setup correctly.

I'm running Android 4.2.2 in the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the manifest needs the ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION permission.